# Как удалить через JS все что в контейнере div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Есть такой контейнер + внизу кнопка

```
<div id="container">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
</div>
<button>Очистить контейнер!</button>
```

как удалить все, что есть в контейнере с помощью **JavaScript**?!

Мне намекнули что-то про `.setHTML` - но я не понял что это.

P.S. ТОЛЬКО БЕЗ:

`var deleteElement = document.getElementById("container");`

`deleteElement.remove();`

Answer (score 3):

Tогда используйте [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

```js
function deleteItems() {
  
  const deleteElement = document.querySelector("#container");

  deleteElement.innerHTML = '';
  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="deleteItems()" >Очисть контейнер!</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function deleteItems() {
  var deleteElement = container.querySelectorAll('div');
  for (let i = 0; i < deleteElement.length; i++) {
    deleteElement[i].remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<button onclick="deleteItems()">Очисть контейнер!</button>
```